# Why doesn't this java post method controller receive this post form?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, forms, http-post

#### This is the form:

```html
<form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadFileForm" action="/uploadTest">
     <div>
        <input type="file" id="image_uploads" name="filename" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf" multiple>
    </div>
    <div id="uploadpreview">
        <p>No files currently selected for upload</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="uploadBtn" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

#### This is the controller:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/**/uploadTest")
public class UserFileUploadController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public String TestRun(@ModelAttribute("filename") final File uploadFile)
    {
    //code in which i use the uploaded file
        return ("redirect:/solutions");
    }
}
```

I get a "405 Method Not Allowed" Status code = the screen shows 'Server error'.
but the page refreshes to /uploadTest so I don't know what is wrong with the controller.

Comment: Please fix code formatting in your question.

Comment: Why did you add `/**` to the path?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace `File` by `MultipartFile`, and then call the `transferTo` method if you want to store the file in the filesystem.

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public String TestRun(@ModelAttribute("filename") final MultipartFile uploadFile) throws IOException {
    File file = ...
    uploadFile.transferTo(file);
    return ("redirect:/solutions");
}
```

You should also check if you have defined this bean in `dispatcher-servler.xml` and set the `maxUploadSize` to a correct value.

```xml
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000" />
</bean>
```